# App log in - Ensure User log in with server

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new to flutter/android, and have been using Firebase Authentication. [I used this for native iOS and Android also.] Its really ideal for those of us who don't know how to build back end servers, since it handles log in, etc.

Now I am working with other servers (not firebase), and everything is http requests. I'm not sure how to handle log in. What I mean is that Firebase would automatically detect if the user was logged in, and the user would stay logged in, even after the app is killed.

How do you do this with a log in from a different server. How you ensure that the user stays logged in, etc.

I'm sorry for the basic question, but I guess I have been spoilt with Firebase, and I'm not sure how to manage these things alone. I also wasn't sure how exactly to the search for this on the internet, so any direction would be of help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Using this package when a user login in to the app, save a value `isLoggedIn` equal to true:

```
SharedPreferences.getInstance().setBool('isLoggedIn', true);
```

and to know if a user is logged in, you can retrieve the value:

```
SharedPreferences.getInstance().getBool('isLoggedIn');
```